# Actually I'm developing a vb .net desktop app that needs to restore a database using a .bak How to do that?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, backup

I'm getting this:

"Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

First the message told me I must connect to master db to execute the restore but I change it and I got the message above.

The parametrized sql statement I'm using is:

cmd.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE aguasdelbosque " +
  "FROM  DISK = @archivo"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to kick all users out of the database, take a look at [Kill All Active Connections To A Database](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Kill_All_Active_Connections_To_A_Database) on how to do it

Comment: or... `USE master GO; DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX); SELECT  @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL, '') + 'Kill ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SPId) + ';' FROM    MASTER..SysProcesses WHERE SPId <> @@SPId AND [dbid] = DB_ID('DATABASE_NAME'); EXEC(@SQL);`

Comment: @Brad if you have a lot of connections while that code is running it is possible that other people get in, it is better to put it in single user mode

Comment: Hi guys thanks a lot... So Can i use this one? : ALTER DATABASE aguasdelbosque SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE                                                              To put in single user mode the database..

Comment: Awsome... That helps me a lot man... I get it... Can u help me how to get the database again as multiuser? Or isnt necesary because it is a standalone application running on one single machine with the server running in the same machine?

Comment: ALTER DATABASE aguasdelbosque  SET MULTI_USER

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to restoring the database is using the [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms212724.aspx) library. To kill all processes, the [Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) class has the method [KillAllProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.killallprocesses.aspx) or [KillDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.killdatabase.aspx). The [Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.aspx) class has the methods [SetOffline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.setoffline.aspx) and [SetOnline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.setonline.aspx). To restore the database you would use the [SqlRestore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.sqlrestore.aspx) method of the [Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220141.aspx) class. For more information or further reading try the links below.

http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=40

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/08416c9d-0e8d-4021-b5ea-b9dc634c03e8

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/52638e68-5c88-49f1-9b76-6bfa2387da18

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/seanprice/archive/2007/07/11/Killing-ProcessIDs-using-SMO.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/BackupRestoreWithSmo.aspx